# How to send a http response and then execute code, all inside a function?

Tags: python, django, webhooks

I'm using Django and I have set a webhook for some events that I need to receive. How can i run some code after sending a response? Something like in this pseudo-code:

```
def my_webhook(request):
    # doing some stuff
    yield HttpResponse('200')
    # doing some other stuff
```

Does it make sense to use a [request_finished](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished) signal to do this? In the django docs I see that when possibile it should be better to avoid signals

Comment: No, even using signals would not solve this, since these work in a synchronous manner: that means that if signals are triggered these will just run and *then* the response is returned.